# mysqldump of single table with where clause // dbname with dots or undescores

Tags: php, mysql, cron, timestamp

I'm trying to set a cronjob pointing to a php script to backup a specific table in a specific database.

Crontab is working.
PHP from CLI is working.

Here's the PHP code I'm trying to use :

```
<?php

$host = 'crm_host_be';
$db = 'db_crm_be';
// Define the database settings
require('/var/www/'.$host.'/data_'.$db.'.php');

// connect to the database
$link = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_SERVER_USERNAME, DB_SERVER_PASSWORD);
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link);
mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);

// Get Offers list
$get_offers_list = 'SELECT * FROM crm_offers ORDER BY date_of_change DESC ';
$q_offers_list = mysql_query($get_offers_list);

while($offers_list = mysql_fetch_array($q_offers_list)) {
//echo $offers_list['offer_uid']."\n";
$ouid = $offers_list['offer_uid'];

mysqldump -u "db_crm_be_u" -p'1234567890' --databases db_crm_be crm_offers --where="offer_uid=\"".$ouid.\"" > 'date +\%Y\%m\%d_\%H\%M\%S'.$ouid.sql

    }
?>
```

The connection to the DB and SELECT is OK (echos each Offer_ID in CLI).

But I'm getting this in CLI :

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '"db_crm_be_u"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /var/www/crm_host_be/db_offers_backup.php on line 35
```

I'd like to keep the variables usage ($host, $db, $ouid, ...) in order to generate a timestamp-based .sql per "unique offer" in the CRM.

Both my DB and TABLES have underscores in their names.

How can I decently solve this without being forced to rename the whole thing ?

Also, how to combine both the timestamp and the suffix of each specific offer ($ouid) to generate the filename ?

Thank you all in advance for your assistance.

Comment: `mysqldump` is a shell command, not a PHP function.

Comment: @PdC-Stack: See B Desai's answer and the remark about the path to mysqldump

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute command. first save it as string then execute using `exec`

```
$mysql_cmd = "mysqldump -u db_crm_be_u -p1234567890 --databases db_crm_be crm_offers --where=offer_uid=\"".$ouid."\" > date +\%Y\%m\%d_\%H\%M\%S".$ouid.".sql";
exec($mysql_cmd);
```

Comment: you may want to use the complete path to mysqldump there. When running from cron the default search path may be missing

Comment: Yes but if default path is there its not needed. I just have given clue

Comment: Yes.. you are write @PdC-Stack will get it from your comment. :p